# cant install bootstrap in new rails 6rc1 project - error in harmony-module.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4

I've got a new rails project (6.0.0rc1) and I'm attempting to use the new webpack system to load bootstrap.

For reference, this is a mac running Mojave, with no known problems when doing any other dev work.

I've followed all relevant tutorials and always end up with the same error, and am unable to load either the js or the stylesheets.

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

config/webpack/environment:

```rb
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Poppper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```rb
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

The error:

```
TypeError: __webpack_require__(/*! ./harmony-module.js */
"./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js") is not a 
function.

(In '__webpack_require__(/*! ./harmony-module.js */
"./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js")(module)',
'__webpack_require__(/*! ./harmony-module.js */
"./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js")' is an instance 
of Object)
```

and, yes the webpack dev server is running and not complaining:

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 1c7e3fa63a51751518ef
Version: webpack 4.32.2
Time: 610ms
Built at: 2019-05-29 2:43:34 p.m.
                                     Asset       Size       Chunks                 
Chunk Names
js/application-40d856ea775503923ce0.js   2.05 MiB  application   
[emitted]  application
js/application-40d856ea775503923ce0.js.map   2.02 MiB  application  
[emitted]  application
                         manifest.json  364 bytes                 
[emitted]  
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with Rails webpacker directly at this time - https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/2031 and not related to bootstrap in webpacker.

Removing the two references to corejs 3 in /babel.config.js solved the issue.

also see https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2109